# tensorflow build from source get -no-as-needed error on darwin(OS X)

Tags: tensorflow

I'd like to upgrade my tensorflow version from 1.5 to the latest version.

I followed the instruction [https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources] step by step,
It's OK on my ubuntu PC, but I met a compile issue on my macbook, 
**ld: unknown option: -no-as-needed**

Does anyone know how to avoid this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Bazel: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5468. Try using a previous version.